# javascript dispatchevent callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

I have two nested select, once I change the first one the second take some values (according the first)

**My problem comes when I try to put a default value in the first select and load html**.

If I use the console and manually execute:

```
    const e = new Event("change");
    
    first_select.dispatchEvent(e);
```

and after

```
    second_select.dispatchEvent(e);
```

**Everything works fine**.

But, when I want to do automatically, I used callback function as the next:

```
    function function1(callback){
            first_select.dispatchEvent(e);
            console.log("1")
            callback();
        }
    
        function function2(){
            second_select.dispatchEvent(e);
            console.log("2")
        }
    
        function1(function2);
```

In the console output I see 1 and after 2, but the second select do not show me any values.

It is like the `second_select.dispatchEvent(e);` never get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a live example on how to do that

```js
let secondSelect = document.querySelector("select[name='sublist']"),
  choices = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i']];

document.querySelector("select[name='list']").onchange = function() {
  secondSelect.innerHTML = choices[this.value - 1].map( v => `<option value="${v}">${v}</option>`).join("");
}
```

```html
<select name="list">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="sublist">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

Here is a more dynamic solution, you can add as much properties as you want and the same for their values, so you can create any changing lists you want.

```js
let firstSelect = document.querySelector("select[name='list']"),
    secondSelect = document.querySelector("select[name='sublist']"),
    choices = {
      fruits: ["apple", "orange", "mango", "kiwi"],
      vegetables: ["potato", "tomato", "onion"]
};

firstSelect.onchange = function() {
  // just get the right property from choices and loop over that
  // array and create  an option from each item
  secondSelect.innerHTML = choices[this.value].map( v => `<option value="${v}">${v}</option>`).join("");
};

// initialise the second select for the first time
firstSelect.onchange();
```

```html
<select name="list">
  <option value="fruits">fruits</option>
  <option value="vegetables">vegetables</option>
</select>

<select name="sublist">
</select>
```